# dispay json data in ngfor loop in angular (data from firebase)

Tags: json, angular, http

In my Angular code, I am getting data from a firebase database through an Http get request and when I try to display the result with an ngfor loop, I have an error message. This example was replicated from a tutorial and it worked for him. Where is the problem and how could I make it work? Thanks for helping!

I use a service to get data here is the code:

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Response} from "@angular/http";
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';



@Injectable()

export class ServerService {
constructor(private http:Http){}

StoreServers(servers:any[]){
return this.http.post('https://ng-http-a5718.firebaseio.com/data.json',servers);
}

GetServers(){
 return  this.http.get('https://ng-http-a5718.firebaseio.com/data.json').pipe(map(
  (res:Response) =>{
    const dataserver = res.json() as any[];
  for(const server of dataserver ){
    server.name='fetched_server'+server.name
  }     
  return dataserver;
}
  )
 )
}

}
```

Here is the .ts code of the component where I try to display the data:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerService } from './server.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
constructor(private ServerService : ServerService){}



  servers = [
    {
      name: 'Testserver',
      capacity: 10,
      id: this.generateId()
    },
    {
      name: 'Liveserver',
      capacity: 100,
      id: this.generateId()
    }
  ];
  onAddServer(name: string) {
    this.servers.push({
      name: name,
      capacity: 50,
      id: this.generateId()
    });
  }
  private generateId() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);
  }


  OnSave(){
    this.ServerService.StoreServers(this.servers).subscribe(
      (Response)=>(console.log(Response)),
      (Error)=>(console.log(Error))
      )
  }

  OnGet(){
    this.ServerService.GetServers().subscribe(
      (data) => { this.servers=data}
        ,
      (Error)=>{
        return (console.log(Error));
      }
      )
  }
}
```

Here is the html code of the component where I try to display the data:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
      <input type="text" #serverName>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddServer(serverName.value)">Add Server</button>
      <hr>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)='OnSave()'>Save servers</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)='OnGet()'>Get servers</button>
      <br>
      <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let server of servers">
        <li class="list-group-item">{{ server.name }} (ID: {{ server.id }})</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And finally here it is the error message I get:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDZmv.png)

Comment: log the server response data. check the response type. Response should be array  look like 'server' property. ngFor can iterate on array or iterator type.
-> 
this.ServerService.GetServers().subscribe(
      (data) => { console.log(data); this.servers=data}

Comment: here is the log   https://imgur.com/LeHOsQ1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.server expecting Array in `onGet()` method but getting Object from firebase with the unique key. so you can modify `onGet()` method in following:

```js
OnGet(){
    this.ServerService.GetServers().subscribe(
      (data) => { 
      const keys = Object.keys(data);
      const firstKey = keys[0];
      this.servers = data[firstKey]; // get the inside array
      
      }
        ,
      (Error)=>{
        return (console.log(Error));
      }
      )
  }
```

Comment: thanks a lot @HelloLinkon for your help, it worked with your piece of code, but still wonder why it worked for him.

Comment: one more thing. you will only get the first item's array. if you want all then you need to loop through all `keys` and contact all data to `this.server`.